# New column for non md5 passwords is not not updating according to my WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysqli

Good day

I have added a column in my database where I want to use the existing password, hash it and update the passwordNonMd5 column with the newly hashed passwords. I have included echos to test that every password is receiving their assigned hash. BUT my database updates with only one hash password in all the passwordNonMd5 rows.

Can someone please point out my mistake ?

Thank You

```
include_once 'dbh.php';
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    ini_set('memory_limit','1000M');            

    $query = "SELECT password FROM users";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $password =  $row["password"];
       echo "$password ";
       $newHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
       echo "New Hash is: " . $newHash . "\n";
       $insert = "UPDATE users SET passwordNonMd5 = '$newHash'
       WHERE password = $password";
       $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $insert);
        }
    }
```

Comment: woah, you can't update passwords like that, what if two people happened to have the same hash?

Comment: Don’t concatenate SQL strings. Use parameters. It will fix this (missing quotes which should give an error) and make things a lot safer. And it seems the password handling isn’t very safe

Comment: `WHERE password = $password` ... does this code even _run_?  You are comparing the `password` column against some non string literal, which will probably be interpreted as a column name.

Comment: This makes sense thank you

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
$res = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
  // You could salt the password here to make hashes more likely to be unique
  // example: $newPass = password_hash( $row['id'] . $row['password'] . $row['perUserOrSystemDefinedSecret'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
  $newPass = password_hash( $row['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT );

  // We can sql inject ourself here but as the data is hashed or is probably a integer we should be fine.
  $updateSql = 'UPDATE users SET passwordNonMd5 = "' . $newPass . '" WHERE id = ' . $row['id'];

  mysqli_query( $conn, $updateSql );

}
```